# install apache2 in linux after removing old installation

Tags: linux, apache2.2

while searching for installing `apache web server` in `linux ubuntu lucid` ,I found that some articles use the name `apache2` while others use `httpd`..Is `apt-get install apache2` the correct way to install?

I want to remove all of my current apache2 installation ,and install everything fresh. Should I use

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2
```

I currently have apache in    `/etc/apache2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache2 is Ubuntu's name for the Apache httpd version 2 branch (currently using 2.2, I think). The best source for information on Ubuntu packages is probably its own documentation; see https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html. But yes, those two commands are correct.